# Why does xlwings.App(visible = False) not work in my code?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to use xlwings to loop through my excel calculations using Python. I have a function that uses xlwings:

```
def obtain_gwp(filename):
    app = xw.App(visible=False)
    print(app.visible)
    wbxl = app.books.open(filename)
    app.visible = False
    print(app.visible)

    print('Obtaining MRF GWP allocated to plastics...')
    app.calculate()

    global pet_sorting
    pet_sorting = wbxl.sheets['Input'].range('H27').value
    plastic_sorting_gwp = wbxl.sheets['GWP Model'].range('I19').value
    print(pet_sorting,plastic_sorting_gwp)

    wbxl.save()
    app.kill()
    return plastic_sorting_gwp
```

But every time I print the value of app.visible, it is True! It never registers the False - not sure why that is happening as I explicitly don't want to have Excel open. Any input/help would be valuable!

Comment: To add more information - this is on MacOS with Excel 2016.

Comment: This isn't really supported by macOS, see: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/652